# How to prove the product of the first n terms of an infinitesimal sequence is infinitesimal?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

If $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=0$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty}(a_1a_2\cdots a_n)=0$. How to use the definition of a convergence sequence to prove that? Any hints would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can show that there exists some $N$ such that for $n>N$, you have $|a_i| < 1$.

Now, define $M=|a_1\cdot a_2\cdots a_N|$
Once you have that, you can see that for $n>N$, you have

$$|a_1\cdot a_2\cdots a_n| = M\cdot |a_{N+1}| \cdot |a_{N+2}| \cdots |a_n| \leq M\cdot |a_n|$$

It should be easy from here on.

Comment: Then we can use Pinching Theorem to show the limit is 0, am I right?

Comment: @HanTang That's one way, yes.

Answer (score 2):

for any sequence of numbers one has
$$
|a_1a_2···a_{N+k}|\le |a_1a_2···a_{N}|·\Bigl(\sup_{n>N}|a_n|\Bigr)^k
$$
As $a_n\to 0$,you now can find the existence of an $N$ such that, as example, $\sup_{n>N}|a_n|<\frac12$.

Comment: The $\sup$ could be replaced by $\max$, but that's nitpicking. Great answer, love the fact that the approach is slightly different than mine.

Answer (score 0):

FIrst of all, you can assume that $a_n \neq 0$ for every $n$ (otherwise the product is zero). Then take logarithms:
$$
\log \left| a_1 a_2 \cdots a_n \right| = \sum_{k=1}^n \log |a_k| \to +\infty
$$
as $n \to +\infty$, since $\log |a_k| \to +\infty$ as $k \to +\infty$ by assumption. Hence $|a_1 a_2 \cdots a_n| \to 0$ as $n \to +\infty$.